# How to disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP on pfSense via DHCP

Tags: pfsense, dhcp-server, netbios, dhcp-option

I have a pfSense applicance running version 2.x. I want to disable NetBios over TCP/IP via the DHCP Server so it is not activated on Windows clients. It's possible to [do it with a Windows server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313314) but I can't find a way to do it properly on pfSense. Reading [this tutorial](http://pfsensesetup.com/dhcp-configuration-in-pfsense/), I thought not configuring a WINS server was sufficient, but it appears not. The only place where I found an option is in the OpenVPN section.

Any hints on how to do disable NetBios via DHCP server on pfSense ?

Thank you.
Florent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an additional option of 43 / String / 01:04:00:00:00:02

[image: screen shot of option 43]